# Law of total expectation for three variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I am working on this question [Conditional probability - need help on calculating numerator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3751245/conditional-probability-need-help-on-calculating-numerator) and I got into use of the law of total expectation. How using this law I can find
$$
E(X_1^2X_2^4X_3^6\mid X_1+X_2+X_3=A),
$$
where $X_i$ are geometric random variables  representing the number of failures with parameter $p$.

I am not sure that I am using the law properly. I am starting with $E(E(E(X_3^6\mid A-X_1-X_2=a_3)\times X_2^4\mid A-X_1=a_2)\times X_1^2\mid X_1+X_2+X_3=A)$

Comment: The $X_i$ are i.i.d.?

Comment: Yes, they are i.id but under condition that their sum is equal to $A$. So, technically, they are not independent.

Comment: Conditionally, they are not independent.  Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go is to figure out the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ given $X_1+X_2+X_3=A$. Take $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ so that $x_1,x_2,x_3 \geq 0$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3 = A$. Try computing
$$
P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,X_3=x_3 | X_1+X_2+X_3=A)
$$
by using the definition of conditional expectation. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415259/conditional-probability-distribution-with-geometric-random-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1) for a similar calculation where you have two instead of three random variables. I think you should get that $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ given $X_1+X_2+X_3=A$ is uniformly distributed, where each possible value $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ with $x_1+x_2+x_3=A$ has probability $\frac2{(A+1)(A+2)}$. Then
$$
E[X_1^2X_2^4X_3^6 | X_1+X_2+X_3=A] = \frac2{(A+1)(A+2)} \sum_{(x_1,x_2,x_3): x_1+x_2+x_3=A} x_1^2 x_2^4 x_3^6.
$$
This at least gives you a computable formula for the conditional expectation.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask you to elaborate on why each $(x_1,x_2, x_3)$ has probability $2/(A+1)(A+2)$?

Comment: Calculate $P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,X_3=x_3|X_1+X_2+X_3=A)$. This probability is only nonzero when $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ satisfies $x_1,x_2,x_3 \geq 0$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3=A$. For such $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, you have \begin{align*} & P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,X_3=x_3|X_1+X_2+X_3=A) \\ & =P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,X_3=x_3)/P(X_1+X_2+X_3=A). \end{align*} You can compute the numerator by using that $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are iid geometric, and you can compute the denominator by using that $X_1+X_2+X_3$ has the negative binomial distribution. You should end up with $2/((A+1)(A+2))$. Try working it out, happy to help if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your help.